# Elicit Slot not prompting for user input in Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have written a lambda function to take user input and then confirm the input. if the user presses `2`, then the function should prompt the user to re enter the slot value. when the user presses 2. the flow is going to the elicit slot function, but not prompting the user to enter value.

```
request = {
                "sessionAttributes": {
                    "lastname": str(last_name),
                    "ssn": str(ssn)
                },
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "ElicitSlot",
                    "intentName": "UserInput",
                 "slots": {
                   "lastname": str(last_name),
                    "SSN": str(ssn)
                      },
                "slotToElicit": "File"
              }
            }
```

Comment: This needs more information. Where is this function being run? In what program? Please show the lambda function code.

Comment: the program flow is : 
1. take user input of name and SSN  from lex bot. 
2. ask user to confirm ssn. ( 1 to confirm and 2 to re enter)
3. if user enters 1, the program moves forward 
4. if for the same name there are 2 SSN system asks user to enter pin. pin+name+ssn is unique combination.
5. process the input by passing on the values to a web api and then return the output. 
this process works fine for taking user input on step 4.
6. if the user enters 2 in step 2, we need to make the user re enter the SSN. the elicit slot for that is not working.

Comment: So slotToElicit would be `SSN` and not `File` in the posted code?

Comment: that's right. but even when we put SSN, it does not prompt the user.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to elicit a slot from the user, ensure that the slot value is currently empty, else Lex will not prompt the user to enter the slot again.

Since the `slotToElicit` would be `SSN`, **do not** return that key in the `slots` JSON object in the response from the Lambda function. Lex will then treat this slot as empty and should prompt the user to enter it.